# Put a form json response inside a div block (not a iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, iframe

I'm trying to catch a json form response into a div block but I can't... 
The example shown below sends a video file and other parameters when the form is submitted. It returns a json response and put it inside an iframe. The parent window and the iframe belong to different domains so the info inside the iframe (postFrame) cannot be accessed via javascript.

Any idea about how to put the response in a div (or similar)?

I appreciate any help.

NOTE: In the example, I added a button (submitButtonNew) that performs the submit of the form using jquery and tries to redirect the response to a callback function (as I've seen in some examples) but it does'nt work fine. If I delete the target parameter of the form, the response is returned in a new page.

```
<html> 
<head>
  <title>Media API: JavaScript Example - create_video with tags and itemState</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doFileUpload(){
  form = document.getElementById("create_video_sample");
  buildJSONRequest(form);
  form.action = document.getElementById("yourAPILocation").value;
  form.submit();
}

function buildJSONRequest(form){
  if(document.getElementById('name').value =="" || document.getElementById('shortDescription').value =="" || form.filePath.value ==""){
    alert("Require Name, Short Description and File");
    return;
  }else{
    json = form.JSONRPC
    //Construct the JSON request:
    json.value = '{"method": "create_video", "params": {"video": {"name": "' + 
    document.getElementById('name').value +  '","tags": ["'+ document.getElementById('tagvalue1').value +'","'+ document.getElementById('tagvalue2').value +'","'+ document.getElementById('tagvalue3').value +'"],"shortDescription": "' + document.getElementById('shortDescription').value +'","itemState": "'+document.getElementById('itemState').value+'"},"token": "'+ document.getElementById('yourWriteToken').value + '","encode_to":"'+document.getElementById('encodeto').value+'","create_multiple_renditions": "'+document.getElementById('rendition').value+'"}}';   
    form.JSONView.value = json.value;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    form = document.getElementById("create_video_sample");
    form.action = document.getElementById("yourAPILocation").value;
    var datajson = '{"method": "create_video", "params": {"video": {"name": "' + document.getElementById('name').value +  '","tags": ["'+ document.getElementById('tagvalue1').value +'","'+ document.getElementById('tagvalue2').value +'","'+ document.getElementById('tagvalue3').value +'"],"shortDescription": "' + document.getElementById('shortDescription').value +'","referenceId": "'+document.getElementById('referenceId').value +'","itemState": "'+document.getElementById('itemState').value+'"},"token": "'+ document.getElementById('yourWriteToken').value + '","encode_to":"'+document.getElementById('encodeto').value+'","create_multiple_renditions": "'+document.getElementById('rendition').value+'"}}';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(datajson);

    $('#create_video_sample').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
        event.preventDefault();
        /* post method */
        var posting = $.post( $(this).attr('action'), jsonObj);

        posting.done(function( data )
        {
            alert("hola");
            /* Put the results in a div */
            $( "#newdiv" ).html(data);
        });
    });

    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
        form = document.getElementById("create_video_sample");
        buildJSONRequest(form);
        form.action = document.getElementById("yourAPILocation").value;
        $("#create_video_sample").submit();
    });
});
</script>

<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:24">create_video example: Upload a Video</div>
(Only a Name, Short Description and Video File are required to create a video) <br/>
<!-- Exposing the token like this is a *Bad_Idea* !! Please don't do this in production, it makes it less than trivial for someone to steal your token.
See http://help.brightcove.com/developer/docs/mediaapi/security.cfm for more info -->

<table style="width:50%">
<tr><td style="width:20%">Write Token: </td><td style="width:100%"><input id="yourWriteToken" size="55" value="ZY4Ls9Hq6LCBgleGDTaFRDLWWBC8uoXQHkhGuDebKvjFPjHb3iT-4g.."/><br/>
</td></tr> 
<tr><td>API Location: </td><td><input id="yourAPILocation" size="55" value="http://api.brightcove.com/services/post" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Video Name: </td><td><input id="name" size="55" type="text" value="testVideo"/></td>
      <tr><td>Tag1: </td><td><input id="tagvalue1" size="55" type="text" value="Tag 1"/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Tag2: </td><td><input id="tagvalue2" size="55" type="text" value="Tag 2"/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Tag3: </td><td><input id="tagvalue3" size="55" type="text" value="Tag 3"/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Short description: </td><td><input id="shortDescription" size="55" type="text" value="test Video"/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Create Multiple Renditions(TRUE/FALSE): </td><td><input id="rendition" size="55" type="text" value="true"/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Encode to(MP4/FLV): </td><td><input id="encodeto" size="55" type="text" value="MP4"/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Video State </td><td><input id="itemState" size="55" type="text" value="ACTIVE"/></td></tr>

<br/> <br/>
<form id="create_video_sample" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="postFrame">
  <!--This is where the actual json request lives, it has to come before the file input -->
  <input type="hidden" name="JSONRPC" />
  <tr><td>File:</td><td><input type="file" name="filePath"/></td></tr>
</table><br/><br/>
  <button id="submitButton" onclick="doFileUpload()">Upload</button> <br/>
  <button id="submitButtonNew">Upload and put in a div</button> <br/>
  <!--display the json request -->

  <div id="newdiv"></div>

  <fieldset>
  <legend>JSON Request</legend>
    <input name="JSONView" id="JSONView" style="width:100%;border:none"/>
  </fieldset><br/>
</form>

<br/>

<fieldset>
<legend>Response:</legend>
  <iframe id="postFrame" name="postFrame" style="width:100%;border:none"></iframe>
</fieldset>

<br/><br/>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$( "#newdiv" ).html(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it doesn't work because my problem is that the function "done" never executes... I've seen many examples where they do like this and work fine, but it's not my case. I think (but I'm not sure) that the problem is that the domain of the page and the domain of the form post are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to see why the post is not fired and never "done".

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
}).done(function() {
     alert( "second success" );
}).fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
}).always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
alert( "second finished" );
});
```